# 3D Analyst missing from Tool Boxes in ArcGIS 9.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, installation, 3d-analyst

I have a missing 3D Analyst from ArcGIS 9.3 (ArcMap - ArcInfo). I need it for a task to be done.

How can i install it? Does anybody know it? Should i donwload the extension or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

The **3D Analyst** extension is installed from the same media, or via the same means, that you used to install ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.  You simply ensure that extension is chosen during the install process.

You will need a 3D Analyst license.  That is obtained through the same mechanism that you use to obtain ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 licensing.

Finally, you need to enable the 3D Analyst extension and that process is described in the **[ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 Online Help](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Enabling_the_ArcGIS_3D_Analyst_extension)**:

> Before you can work with ArcGIS 3D Analyst in ArcMap or ArcCatalog,
>   you must enable the ArcGIS 3D Analyst extension.